# How to set attribute target in form using jquery when validation is finish?

Tags: jquery, zend-framework

I am using zend and  validating form in server side.I display form in fancybox. I use `target=_top` in zend form, So that i can redirect to parent page once validation finish, Here my problem is ,Everytime it redirects to parent page if validation is not ok because of target=_top, Is it possible to give attribute target=_top after validation is ok using jquery ?.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#form_id').attr('target',url);
```

Comment: Thanks but i need to set the target attribute only when validation is ok

Comment: Do you use jquery validation?
if($('#form_id').valid()){ 
   $('#form_id').attr('target',url);
}

Comment: yes i tried it now but once validation is done its not redirecting to parent page.Page is being displayed inside ifram iteself, I need to redirect to parent page

Comment: Ah. In that case you need to call window.opener.fnSubmit(); bearing in mind that fnSubmit is a function in the parent page that will submit the page.